# sprite for hover effect sliding from image to image

Tags: css

I have a social icons in sprite image, and hover effect is sliding when hovering.

I don't want it to, I want it to act just like if i use a regular image, when hover an image the image is changed, also I want to add CSS3 transitions to it.

This is the site: [**Site**][1]

[image]

```
/*Social Icons*/
#social_icons { 
    width: 18%;
    height: 37px; 
    display: inline; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 185px;
}

.social-roll {
    height: 40px; 
    width: 42px; 
    margin: -3px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    -webkit-transition:  all 0.9s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out; }

.ico-facebook, .ico-facebook-hover, .ico-googlep, .ico-googlep-hover, .ico-linkedin, 
.ico-linkedin-hover, .ico-message, .ico-p, .ico-p-hover, .ico-twitter, 
.ico-twitter-hover{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: url('../images/icons/social.png') no-repeat; 
    overflow: hidden; }

.ico-facebook {
    background-position: -3px -0px; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-facebook:hover {
    background-position: -46px -0px;
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-googlep {
    background-position: -89px -0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-googlep:hover {
    background-position: -3px -43px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-linkedin {
    background-position: -46px -43px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-linkedin:hover {
    background-position: -89px -43px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-message {
    background-position: -3px -86px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-p {
    background-position: -46px -86px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-p:hover {
    background-position: -89px -86px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-twitter {
    background-position: -3px -129px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.ico-twitter:hover {
    background-position: -46px -129px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

[1]:

Comment: Can you post the code you have?

Comment: Just remove the javascript you are using for this action

Comment: i am not using any javascript for that

Comment: Remove `transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s` from `.social-roll`

Comment: @MLeFevre thanks! it worked, how can i add nice transition when hovering?

Comment: Decide on a transition effect that you want/Search the internet for some, then use it?

Comment: Would it not make sense to have all the sprites on one line? By the looks of it you have the FB and TW sprites on the same line yet the G+ one is on the next one. It would make sense to have them all on the same vertical line and change the transition as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the transition effect:

```
.social-roll {
    height: 40px;
    width: 42px;
    margin: -3px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s; */
}
```

Note: You need to specify what kind of transition you want

Comment: where do i specify the transition? i thought the it suppose to be in the .social-roll:hover

Comment: You must specify on the .social-roll. Thus if you like to make a smooth transition, you must set images separately on normal and hover.

Comment: For me the best choice to do what you want the best is font awesome -http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ You can manipulate color, size, animation, etc...

Comment: so i can't use a sprite fr nice transitions? i need to set a separate image for each? "font awesome" is it free for commercial use?
can you please post a jsFiddle with a simple example using it?

Comment: With sprite you get transitions that you don´t want. And yes font-awesome is free for comercial use...and you get a lot of icons to use in your website. As i said you can manipulate them by CSS, no need a image editor. It´s only advantages :). Is treated like a font.

Answer (score 0):

You have a rule set defined as below

.social-roll {

```
display: inline-block;
height: 40px;
margin: -3px;
transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out 0s;
width: 42px;
```

}

either you remove the transition property from the above rule or add a new property in the below rule set

.ico-facebook, .ico-facebook-hover, .ico-googlep, .ico-googlep-hover, .ico-linkedin, .ico-linkedin-hover, .ico-message, .ico-p, .ico-p-hover, .ico-twitter, .ico-twitter-hover {

transition: none;

}